# I tried to deploy abp multitenant core app on shared server but failed

Tags: angular, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I tried abp **multitenant .Net Core + Angular app**  hosting on my shared server but I could not deploy it successfully.

I added a json file under `MyProject.Web.Host/appsettings.production.json` and configure my settings as

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    // "Default": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=mydatabase; Trusted_Connection=True;"
    "Default": "Server=myserverip; Database=myserverdatabase; Trusted_Connection=True; User ID=myuserid; Password=mypassword;"
  },
  "App": {
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://api.myremoteserver.com" 
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://myclientdomain.com",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://myclientdomain.com"
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "JwtBearer": {
      "IsEnabled": "true",
      "SecurityKey": "xxxxxxx",
      "Issuer": "MyCompany",
      "Audience": "MyCompany"
    }
  }
}
```

and I deployed using VS 2017 publish but it was unsuccessful. Remember my remote server is shared server and I have setup angular setting as well but I wanted to run core app on separate url which is `api.mydomain.com` and client app (angular) in separate domain which is `mycleintdomain.com`. Also, my project runs locally and this core plus angular project is not merged one.

I followed [this](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/zero/latest/Step-by-step-publish-to-azure-angular) guideline but my server is not azure. I have one question is that since I added production.json file  do I still need to change anywhere in the server project?

Thank you for your help.

**Update: 
As requested: Error on screen**

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
  Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\e:\MyHostingSpace\myusername\api.example.com\wwwroot\web.config
Requested URL      http://api.example.com:80/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
```

I was requested to change web.config file as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebMVC_Original.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But I have existing one in my project as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The only thing that I need to change is `arguments=".\WebMVC_Original.dll"` instead of `arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"` ... I am little bit confused how to apply this change here?

Comment: *it was unsuccessful* Are we supposed to guess what the error was?

Comment: @DavidG I have updated the post as per your request. Thank you.

Comment: Internal Server Error does not say anything. It is a generic representation of all unhandled errors.

Comment: @Simonare I have updated detail error please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: this still does not give any detail. please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2)